# How can I read and write actor, director and producer data using Applescript?

Tags: applescript, metadata, itunes

Is it possible to access actor, director and producer tags on a movie in iTunes using Applescript?

**This returns empty strings**

```
tell application "iTunes"
    get artist of (track 1 of playlist "Movies")
    get composer of (track 1 of playlist "Movies")
end tell
```

**This gives me an error (*A descriptor type mismatch occurred." number -10001 to item*)**

```
tell application "iTunes"
    get actors of (track 1 of playlist "Movies")
end tell
```

If it's not possible using iTunes as the application, can I use Finder or something else as the application to access the properties I want?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an actors property of the track class, or anywhere else in iTunes.

Comment: Then how would can I access actors using Applescript? Can be through iTunes or Finder.